# nodejs node-libcurl HTTP Authorisation - problems with Bearer Auth Token

Tags: node.js, node-libcurl

I'm coding a nodejs app to retrieve a transcript file from a site via the API. 
 If I use a curl command line everything works fine but I'm getting an

> "Authoristaion Required"

status code back from my nodejs code.

I'm using the "node-libcurl" library and I'm trying to pass the Authorisation code by:

```
const curl = new Curl();
.....
curl.setopt(Curl.option.XOAUTH2_BEARER, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
.....
```

where xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx is the Bearer authorization code.
Is this syntax incorrect?

Comment: Please show the working curl commandline ... With a typical Bearer authentication, you would simply set the `Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxx` header ...

Comment: The working command line includes: -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" as you say simply sets the authorization. But how do you do that in Node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the same headers as in your working call from the cli. According to the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-libcurl#setting-http-headers) this should do the trick

```
curl.setOpt(Curl.option.HTTPHEADER, ['Authorization: Bearer xxxxx'])
```